# updating two or more values in a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Have no idea why this does not work, but here you go.

```
update delievery
set status = 'delivered'
where order_num = 'a563'
and order_num = 'a109';
```

if I were to run this, I get 0 rows updated.

of course I could do this individually, but if I needed to update more than two things, that would not be very efficient.

Comment: You should accept an answer here if any of them solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written your query by using `AND` it simply means both the conditions written with it **must** be true. The condition here is `order_num = 'a563'` and `order_num = 'a109'`. Now if you have a look at your table you will see no row in your whole table where the column `order_num` will be having both the values `a563` and `a109`.

At one time only one value will be there. So both the conditions never get satisfied *at same time*,  therefore no row is updated.

You should use `OR` instead of `AND` in your query. As it will check if any one of the condition is true, then update values. So in one row the value of column `order_num` will be `a563` and in other it will be `a109`, hence both will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation, sorry if anyone perceives this as a dumb question

Comment: @dragonore You are welcome ! and no need to feel sorry ! We are here to learn. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `OR`.  `AND` requires both conditions to be met.

```
update delievery
set status = 'delivered'
where order_num = 'a563'
or order_num = 'a109';
```

You could also use `IN` like this:

```
update delievery
set status = 'delivered'
where order_num IN ('a563', 'a109');
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that since they both needed to be changed, the "and" was required.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use 'OR'

```
update delievery set status = 'delivered' 
where order_num = 'a563' or order_num = 'a109';
```

....

```
order_num   || Status
---------------------
a563         pending

a564         deliverd

a109         pending

a110         pending
```